# javascript only works once, on first <a>

Tags: javascript, php

I am making "food blog" project where you can add and delete a category to the recipe sucha as pasta, veggie and vlees (=meat). it works fine with php but when I try to do it with javascript the adding of a category works fine but the deletion of a category only works on the first element. on all other elements, even elements(categories) I added with javascript it just does it with php and not with javascript for some reason.

So I need to find in the javascript what is causing it to only work on the first one.

JAVASCRIPT. the function that deletes the category is handleClickDelete and the event listener is in the init();

```
const handleClickDelete = async e => {
      
            const confirmed = window.confirm('Bent u zeker dat u deze categorie wilt verwijderen?');

            e.preventDefault();
          

            if (!confirmed) {
              return
            }
          
            let getcategoryId = new URLSearchParams(`${document.querySelector('.detail__link').getAttribute('href')}`);
        console.log(getcategoryId);
        const categoryId = getcategoryId.get('category_id');
        console.log(categoryId);
      
        const url = `${document.querySelector('.detail__link').getAttribute('href')}`;
        console.log(url);
        
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const recipeId = searchParams.get('id');
        console.log(recipeId);
        
       
        // versturen naar de juiste route op de server en aangeven dat we een JSON response verwachten
        // de parameter body bevat de data 
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: categoryId,
                recipe_id: recipeId,
                action: "deletePost"
            })
            
            
            
        });
        
        // PHP Response. Contains error or updated reaction value
        
        const returned = await response.json();

        
        console.log(returned);
        
        

        showCategories(returned);
          
        
      

        
        
        


        
        
    };
    


    //insert
   

    const postCategory = async () => {

        let getValue = document.querySelector('.categories_select');
        let categoryId = getValue.value;
        if(categoryId === "-1"){
            return

        }
        
        const url = `${document.querySelector('.form__category').getAttribute('action')}`;
        console.log(url);
        
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const recipeId = searchParams.get('id');
        
        //console.log(url);
        //console.log(test);
        //console.log(test2);
        // versturen naar de juiste route op de server en aangeven dat we een JSON response verwachten
        // de parameter body bevat de data (in dit geval quoten auteur en id van de aflevering)
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),
            body: JSON.stringify({
                category_id: categoryId,
                recipe_id: recipeId,
                action: "add-category"
            })
            
            
        });
        // PHP Response. Contains error or updated reaction value
        
        const returned = await response.json();

        
        console.log(returned);

        
        showCategories(returned);

     
    };

    const showCategories = categories => {
        const $categories = document.querySelector('.detail__foreach');
        // elementen aanmaken via JavaScript ipv via PHP
        $categories.innerHTML = categories.map(category => {
          console.log(category);
          return `
          

          <div class="detail__category--box">
                <p class="detail__category">${category.name} </p>
                <a class="delete-link detail__link" href="index.php?page=detail&id=${category.id}&action=deletePost&category_id=${category.category_id}">delete</a></br>
          </div>
         
          `;
        }).join(``);
        
        
      };
    
    const hideButton = () => {
        const $filterbutton = document.getElementById('submit__button');
        $filterbutton.classList.add('hidden');
      }

    const init = () => {
        const $categoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.categories_select');
        $categoryButtons.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('change', postCategory);
        });

        const links = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-link');
        links.forEach($link =>  {
            $link.addEventListener('click', handleClickDelete);
            
            

        });
        
        
        hideButton();

        
    };

    init();
```

ImagesDAO the `if ($data['action'] == 'deletePost')` is where the deleting gets performed

```
public function jsonAddCategory() 
    {
        //? Add reactions via JS
        // POST from JavaScript
        $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
        if ($contentType === "application/json") {
            $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
            $data = json_decode($content, true);
            

            //? JS REACTION
            // Check if it is add reaction
            if ($data['action'] == 'add-category') {
                $updatedCategory = $this->insertImage($data);

                $category = $this->selectCategoriesByPost($_GET['id']);
                echo json_encode($category);
                exit();
            }

            if ($data['action'] == 'deletePost') {
              $id = $data['id'];
              $recipe_id = $data['recipe_id'];
              $deletedCategory = $this->delete($id, $recipe_id);

            
              $selectedCategory = $this->selectCategoriesByPost($_GET['id']);
              
              echo json_encode($selectedCategory);
              exit();
          }
        };
    }
```

PagesTDTController

```
  public function detail() {
    if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
      $image = $this->imagesDAO->selectById($_GET['id']);
      $this->set('image', $image);
      
      $ingredients = $this->imagesDAO->selectIngredientenById($_GET['id']);
      $this->set('ingredients', $ingredients);

      $categories = $this->imagesDAO->selectAllCategories();
      $this->set('categories', $categories);
      
      $recipe_category = $this->imagesDAO->selectCategoriesById($_GET['id']);
      $this->set('recipe_category', $recipe_category);

      $category_recipes = $this->imagesDAO->selectCategoriesByPost($_GET['id']);
      $this->set('category_recipes', $category_recipes);
      $this->imagesDAO->jsonAddCategory();

   

      

    }
    if (empty($image)) {
      $_SESSION['error'] = 'The post could not be found';
      header('Location: index.php');
      exit();
      
    }


    

    if (!empty($_POST['action'])) {
      if ($_POST['action'] == 'add-category') {
        if($_POST['categories'] != 'Select category'){
          $data = array(
            'recipe_id' => $image['id'],
            'category_id' => $_POST['categories']
          );
          $insertedImage = $this->imagesDAO->insertImage($data, $_GET['id']);
          if (empty($insertedImage)) {
            $errors = $this->imagesDAO->validateImage($data);
            $this->set('errors', $errors);
          } else {
            $_SESSION['info'] = 'Category succesfully added!';
            header('Location: index.php?page=detail&id=' . $image['id']);
            exit();
            
          }

        }
        
        
      }
    }

    if(!empty($_GET['action'])){
      if($_GET['action'] == 'deletePost' && !empty($_GET['category_id'])){
          $this->imagesDAO->delete($_GET['category_id'], $image['id']);
      }
          $_SESSION['info'] = 'Succesfully deleted category!';
          header('Location: index.php?page=detail&id=' . $image['id']);
          exit();
    }



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is most likely `${document.querySelector('.detail__link').getAttribute('href')}` which should utilize `e.target.getAttribute('href')` rather than refetching from DOM, since this will return the first delete link, rather than the one that was clicked.

> You might also notice a slight performance improvement since DOM manipulation is rather expensive

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had to call the event after loading in the categories again and I didn't do that.

Thanks for the help